# How to detach jquery event (function) from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to remove this click event if my ajax request is succesful:

```
  $('.el a').live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('href'),
      type: 'GET',      
      success: function(response){

         // how to detach this function here? (the live click event)
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Instead of 'click' you can add a namespace (looks like a class selector), e.g. 'click.mine'.  Then, you can call `.unbind('click.mine')` on the element to unbind the single event or `.unbind('.mine')` for all events. [more info here](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events)

Comment: The `.live` method will bind to all elements that match the selector now or in the future. Is it your intention to detach the event just from the particular element that was clicked, or from all (other) matching elements now and in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that `live` isn't bound to any specific set of elements, it is bound to whatever elements match a particular selector at the time the click event happens. That means that you can't use `unbind` or `off` to stop the click from triggering the handler.

You can, however, slightly modify your selector to exclude elements with a certain class and then add that class to tell `live` to ignore your element:

```
$('.el a:not(.been-clicked)').live('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: $this.attr('href'),
    type: 'GET',      
    success: function(response){
      $this.addClass('been-clicked');
    }
  });
});
```

Demo of the technique: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Deh5j/

---

Greg Pettit is right in the comments that `live` shouldn't be used anymore if you're using jQuery 1.7 and somewhat frowned upon even in 1.6. You're usually better off using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) before 1.7 and [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you are using 1.7:

```
$(document).on('click', '.el a:not(.been-clicked)', function() {
  //...
});
```

You still can't use `unbind` or `off` to stop this version of `on` (except in very narrow circumstances such as if you only have one element that matches `.el a` and you only have one click handler attached (or if you use a named function)). You still need something like the above "add a class as a flag" trick if you're using "live" style binding, if you're binding to a specific set of elements that exist when you bind your click handler then you shouldn't be using `live` at all, you should be using one of `bind`, `click`, or `on` to bind a handler to just those specific elements; and then you could use `unbind` or `off` to detach the handlers. Or better, you'd just use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and let jQuery worry about detaching the handler.

Comment: D'oh, I'm with you now, Mu. For a moment I hadn't thought of it. Even with the same technique, I would provide Alex the code using `.on()` (if she's using 1.7+) or `.delegate()` otherwise.

Comment: @Greg: I don't know what the HTML looks like so I can't do much with `delegate`. I've added some pointers for the other cases though.

Comment: Certainly makes it difficult. Good on you for the updated post. Wish I could upvote twice. ;-) I usually go with $('someAncestor') and a brief explanation. Good call on the `one` as well; hadn't thought of that one. (groan)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
.unbind("click");
```

or in jQuery 1.7+

```
.off("click");
```

Note: this will remove the `click` event from the clicked element; if you want to stop newly created elements from having a click event (i.e. disable the `live()` method), you'll instead want to do:

```
$('.el a').die("click");
```

Comment: OK just removed the $(this) part to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

<s>This can be done through the use of `.unbind()` but you can't use `this` from inside the success function of the ajax class as it'll be referring to a different object coming from a function callback then the element you clicked on, instead create a variable storing the element clicked on; I used `elem` in this case and use it to unbind your click event on success `$(elem).unbind('click');`</s>

```
$('.el a').live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var elem = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'GET',      
        success: function(response){
            $(elem).unbind('click');
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit**: @mu is too short has pointed out apperently in the previous versions prior to 1.7 it's more difficult then it should be to kill an event set by .live() and his example

Answer (score 0):

use unbind http://api.jquery.com/unbind/